# Firing up a cluster using whirr

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, cloudera

I'm new to whirr and AWS so apologies in advance if I'm asking something silly.

I'm following the directions [here](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/1/4/map-reduce-with-ruby-using-hadoop.html?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email) to set up whirr and

```
bin/whirr launch-cluster --config hadoop.properties
```

fails with the following:

```
[~/src/cloudera/whirr-0.1.0+23]$ bin/whirr version                                                                                                                                       rvm:ruby-1.8.7-p299 
Apache Whirr 0.1.0+23
[~/src/cloudera/whirr-0.1.0+23]$ bin/whirr launch-cluster --config hadoop.properties                                                                                                     rvm:ruby-1.8.7-p299 
Launching myhadoopcluster cluster
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jclouds.credential) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jclouds.credential)
    for parameter 2 at org.jclouds.aws.filters.FormSigner.<init>(FormSigner.java:91)
  at org.jclouds.aws.config.AWSFormSigningRestClientModule.provideRequestSigner(AWSFormSigningRestClientModule.java:66)

1 error
  at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:410)
  at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:166)
  at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:118)
  at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:100)
  at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
  at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
  at org.jclouds.rest.RestContextBuilder.buildInjector(RestContextBuilder.java:141)
  at org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceContextBuilder.buildInjector(ComputeServiceContextBuilder.java:53)
  at org.jclouds.aws.ec2.EC2ContextBuilder.buildInjector(EC2ContextBuilder.java:101)
  at org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceContextBuilder.buildComputeServiceContext(ComputeServiceContextBuilder.java:66)
  at org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceContextFactory.buildContextUnwrappingExceptions(ComputeServiceContextFactory.java:72)
  at org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceContextFactory.createContext(ComputeServiceContextFactory.java:114)
  at org.apache.whirr.service.ComputeServiceContextBuilder.build(ComputeServiceContextBuilder.java:41)
  at org.apache.whirr.service.hadoop.HadoopService.launchCluster(HadoopService.java:84)
  at org.apache.whirr.service.hadoop.HadoopService.launchCluster(HadoopService.java:61)
  at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:61)
  at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.run(Main.java:65)
  at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

My hadoop.properties file has an AWS Access Key and Secret Access Key.

Any pointers on what I might have done wrong and what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so this appears to be a problem with the syntax in my hadoop.properties file.  In the process of copying my keys across from the AWS management console, "Whirr.credential" got truncated to "Whirr.cred."

A classic face palm moment!

Anyway, leaving this up so that anyone googling for this error message knows to go triple check their hadoop.properties file!